# Connection with Oauth 2.0 Google Calendar

Tags: oauth, calendar, authorization

```
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;
//import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.EventAttendee;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.EventDateTime;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleClient.Builder;
//import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Calendars;
//import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Calendars.Insert;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessProtectedResource.Method;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenErrorResponse;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessTokenRequest.GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessProtectedResource;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

@SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unused" })
public class connect{

    public void setUp() throws IOException {

        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        // The clientId and clientSecret are copied from the API Access tab on
        // the Google APIs Console
        String clientId = "MYCLIENTID";
        String clientSecret = "CLIENTSECRET";

        // Or your redirect URL for web based applications.
        String redirectUrl = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
        String scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";

        // Step 1: Autorizzazione -->
        String authorizationUrl = new GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl(clientId, redirectUrl, scope)
            .build();

        // Point or redirect your user to the authorizationUrl.
        System.out.println("Vai al seguente indirizzo nel browser:");
        System.out.println(authorizationUrl);

        // Read the authorization code from the standard input stream.
        System.out.println("Qual e' il tuo codice di autorizzazione?");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String code = in.readLine();

        // Fine Step 1 <--
        // Step 2: Scambio -->
        AccessTokenResponse authResponse = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant(httpTransport, jsonFactory,
                clientId, clientSecret, code, redirectUrl).execute();
        System.out.println("Scrivi: "+authResponse);
        System.out.println("Token d'accesso: "+authResponse.accessToken);
        if(scope == "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar")
        System.out.println("Scope di lettura e scrittura usato :"+scope);
        else
            System.out.println("Scope di sola lettura usato :"+scope);
        // Fine Step 2 <--

        GoogleAccessProtectedResource accessProtectedResource = new GoogleAccessProtectedResource(
                authResponse.accessToken, httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientId, clientSecret,
                authResponse.refreshToken);
        System.out.println("Il Client ID utilizzato e': "+accessProtectedResource.getClientId());
        System.out.println("Il Secret ID utilizzato e': "+accessProtectedResource.getClientSecret());
        System.out.println("L'url di autenticazione e': "+accessProtectedResource.getAuthorizationServerUrl());

        com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar service = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar(httpTransport, jsonFactory);
        Calendar cale = new Calendar();

        System.out.println("Menu'");
        System.out.println("Cosa desideri fare?");
        System.out.println("1) Creare un calendario");
        System.out.println("2) Creare un evento");
        System.out.println("3) Eliminare un calendario");
        System.out.println("0) Uscita");

        int scelta = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        System.out.println(scelta);
        switch(scelta){
        case 1:
            //insert calendar
            Calendar ClaudioCal = new Calendar();
            ClaudioCal.setSummary("Esempio di calendario di Claudio");
            ClaudioCal.setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");

            cale = service.calendars().insert(ClaudioCal).execute();
            break;

            //other case.......

        System.out.println("Fatto"); 
    }
    }
```

Hi people, this is my code to connect at Google Account to modify the Calendar, but everytime the system response me "Unauthorized". Like as the accessToken isn't verified, i don't understand where's the problem

please help me
thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Please provide step-by-step information on what happened.  When did you get the Unauthorized exception?  What's the stack trace?  Is there information in the body of the HTTP response which would tell you more information about the reason for error?  Did you enable the calendar API in the google APIs console for your project?  etc.

Comment: calendar apis are enabled, at this point 
        System.out.println(authorizationUrl);  i browse it, than i click allow access to my progett and the code appaer. I copy it into my program String code = in.readLine(); than when i set create calendar in mine menu', at this point cale = service.calendars().insert(ClaudioCal).execute(); the program fail with unauthorized exception...it seems like my program doesn't verify the code with accessToken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest version of the Java API library, the mechanism for handling OAuth has changed significantly.

You'll want to follow the builder pattern referenced in the sample code here:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/calendar-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/calendar/cmdline/CalendarSample.java?repo=samples#57

```
Credential credential = OAuth2Native.authorize(
    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, new LocalServerReceiver(),
    Arrays.asList(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR));

// set up global Calendar instance
client = com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY)
    .setApplicationName("Google-CalendarSample/1.0").setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
    .build();
```

This automatically handles the prompting for you (and even does some great magic on desktops to open up the browser).  Alternatively, if you're looking for how to do this under the covers, more information is here:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/shared/shared-sample-cmdline/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/shared/cmdline/oauth2/OAuth2Native.java?repo=samples#102

Comment: when the core go to loadClientSecret in class Oauth2Native, it loads the client ID and Client secret correctly, but when he does the GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder() with the variables clientSecrets it fails, if i set like that GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
          transport, jsonFactory, "clientId", "clientSecret", scopes).build(); all work well.Why before fail with clientSecrets variable? ( clientSecrets is a GoogleClientSecrets object ) also Preconditions.checkArgument method fail because he try to evaluate the wrong condition on the file

Answer (score 0):

After you setup your `GoogleAccessProtectedResource` object, you're not passing it into the Calendar service class correctly.

Change this:

```
com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar service = 
    new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar(httpTransport,
                                                  jsonFactory);
```

to this:

```
com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar service = 
    new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar(httpTransport, 
                                                  accessProtectedResource, 
                                                  jsonFactory);
```

That should do it.

Comment: The constructor Calendar(HttpTransport, GoogleAccessProtectedResource, JacksonFactory) is undefined

Comment: i have these import                                              import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;
//import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar;      //import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Calendars;

Comment: So, looks like the way OAuth is handled entirely changed with recent versions of the library.  I'll answer again below with the updated way with the latest library.

Comment: but i have downloaded tha last version of the apis google library, the 1.9.0, but the constructor of calendar is without the 3rd parameter.